# In Mac Os, what is .DS_store?

Tags: files, filesystems, osx

In each folder I find a hidden file called .DS_store? What is this exactly?

Answer (score 1):

The [description in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.DS_Store) is quite clear:

> .DS_Store (short for Desktop Services Store)[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.DS_Store) is a hidden file with a proprietary format created by OS X to store custom attributes of a folder such as the position of icons or the choice of a background image